# disable tab with angular based on checkbox

Tags: angular, tabs

i have a tab element and i want to use ng-disabled to disable a tab based on a checkbox in the form

```html
 <li><a href="#tab_3-2" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">tab</a></li>


   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test" id="cb"><b>test</b>
```

So when the checkbox is enabled then disable the tab

Comment: ng-disabled="test" ?  on the link

Comment: but i want it to be disabled when you check the checkbox